# Buildfarm doesn't pick up packages' new release repositories after merge

Tags: ros, bloom-release, rosdistro, buildfarm, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having a similar problem to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/199996/repo-problem-in-build-farm-after-moving-package-out-of-metapackage/), however after 30-odd hours, the updated release repositories still haven't picked up by the buildfarm, and jenkins has been failing the [sourcedeb build](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-husky-base_sourcedeb/109/console) after pulling the wrong release repository.

My case is a little more unorthodox, so I may have broken something - I consolidated a number of packages into unified repositories ([pull](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/e3a61fd945c80ffeeed7da1811baefeb7ea8227f)).

Is there any way I can correct this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205831/buildfarm-doesn%27t-pick-up-packages%27-new-release-repositories-after-merge/) by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-24**:
It might have something to do with renaming the repository in the distribution.yaml file. I'll have to defer to @Dirk Thomas or @tfoote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Last night's [indigo reconfigure job](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/_indigo-reconfigure-release-jobs/483/) failed. It should reconfigure when it runs again tonight.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2